# Current used APN?

Tags: android, configuration, apn

I added two APN configurations and then scanned the APN database.
I noticed that both APN entries are marked as "current=1".

how can I identify the currently active APN configuration programmatically?

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you probably are using:

```
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers/current"), null, null, null, null);
```

This URI returns the entire list of APN. To return only selected APN use:

```
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers/preferapn"), null, null, null, null);
```